# Usar uma array como key para outra array associativa

Tags: php, array

Eu tenho estas duas arrays em php:

```
Array
(
    [0] => nome
    [1] => cargo
    [2] => email
)



Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => nome1
            [1] => cargo1
            [2] => email1@dominio.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => nome2
            [1] => cargo2
            [2] => email2@dominio.com
        )
)
```

Queria combinar as duas de forma que o resultado fosse o seguinte:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nome] => nome1
            [cargo] => cargo1
            [email] => email1@dominio.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nome] => nome2
            [cargo] => cargo2
            [email] => email2@dominio.com
        )

)
```

Alguma ideia de como posso fazer isto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue uma forma para criar a estrutura que citou, código comentado:

```
<?php

// Item para ser o indíce no novo array
$keys =  array( "nome", "cargo", "email" );

// Valores...
$values = array(
    array("nome1", "cargo1", "email1@example.com"),
    array("nome2", "cargo2", "email2@example.com"),
);

// Item que armazenará o novo array
$newValues = array();

// Percorre os valores
foreach($values as $value)
{
    // Array temporário
    $tmp = array();

    // Percorre as chaves
    foreach($keys as $_key => $newKey)
    {
        // Define o indice do array de acordo com o valor de $keys
        // e define o valor buscando de $value passando o indíce numerico
        $tmp[$newKey] = $value[$_key];
    }

    // Insere o objeto no array de saída
    $newValues[] = $tmp;
}

print_r($newValues);

?>
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nome] => nome1
            [cargo] => cargo1
            [email] => email1@example.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nome] => nome2
            [cargo] => cargo2
            [email] => email2@example.com
        )

)
```

Comment: acho que nao percebeu a minha pergunta, isto vai combinar as duas mas não é isso que eu quero...

Comment: Realmente, não havia entendido. Acordei agora.. kkk vou ajustar

Comment: Ajustei o código agora para o que precisa. :P

Comment: Perfeito, é mesmo isso. Obrigado